# Ajax post breaks with special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to pass the value of a textarea to an php page to then be processed and added to a SQL database.

I want the text area to be able to support special characters.

Everything works fine till I put this string in the text area and post it:

> JΛ̊KE#2@#*&($^@%#*@#%))*$&@*("""

I am getting a 501 Not implemented error.

Now when I paste in certain PHP code into the text area (not to run, purely to save as a string), I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Why does the value of the text area affect the error code?

For now, the paste.php file has no code so that I could try and understand where the error is coming from. I am certain the error is coming from the ajax post. I've looked everywhere online but have not been able to find how to make the string safe to post. encodeURIComponent doesn't seem to work in this case.

Here is the JS for the button press:

```
var note = $("#note").val();
var dataString = encodeURIComponent(note);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/paste.php",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    paste: dataString
  }),
  dataType: 'text',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    console.log(msg)
  },
  error: function(ts) {
    alert(ts.responseText)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Does this support all characters?

Comment: Actually, that worked for the characters I had an issue with above, but when I paste some PHP code in the textarea I get a 403 forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

What was needed was to use this function on the data.

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
     return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}
```

Change the content type to

```
ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

and for the kicker, add this to my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
 SecFilterEngine Off
 SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```